# Artifactory Plugin for Jenkins - NPM Install in scripted pipeline is failing

Tags: jenkins, npm, plugins, artifactory

I wanna use Artifactory plugin for my Jenkins Scripted Pipeline for NPM Project. During the NPM Install I'm facing an issue:

```
SEVERE: process hasn't exited
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process hasn't exited
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.exitValue(UNIXProcess.java:423)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.executor.CommandExecutor.exeCommand(CommandExecutor.java:78)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.npm.NpmDriver.runCommand(NpmDriver.java:80)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.npm.NpmDriver.install(NpmDriver.java:42)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.npm.extractor.NpmBuildInfoExtractor.runInstall(NpmBuildInfoExtractor.java:153)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.npm.extractor.NpmBuildInfoExtractor.extract(NpmBuildInfoExtractor.java:61)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.npm.extractor.NpmInstall.execute(NpmInstall.java:50)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.npm.NpmInstallCallable.invoke(NpmInstallCallable.java:53)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.npm.NpmInstallCallable.invoke(NpmInstallCallable.java:20)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:3085)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I'm using [Artifactory plugin for Jenkins (v. 3.2.2)](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in) in Scripted Pipeline in Jenkins. I'm following [official Jfrog Documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins).

I'm already somehow in touch with JFrog support, I've already raised an issue in [official Github](https://github.com/jfrog/jenkins-artifactory-plugin/issues/137) and contributing in issue in JFrog support [here](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP-1165).

I'm already using this plugin for scripted pipeline for maven Project and it works fine. I was trying to debug the issue a lot, sometimes it worked, when I removed some dependencies from **package.json**.

This is the configuration in my groovy script.

```
def server = Artifactory.server 'artifacts-prod-01'
server.credentialsId = 'artifactory-credentials-id'
def rtNpm = Artifactory.newNpmBuild()
rtNpm.resolver server: server, repo: 'npm-main-dev'
withEnv(["PATH+NODEJS=${tool 'NodeJS 10'}/bin"]) {
        def buildInfo = rtNpm.install path: '.'
}
```

I'm expecting to have installed all packages specified in **package.json**, but it seems that during npm install there is a timeout. I have just one interesting point. I tried to install their Snapshot version with fixed timeout [here](https://oss.jfrog.org/oss-snapshot-local/org/jenkins-ci/plugins/artifactory/3.2.x-SNAPSHOT/artifactory-3.2.x-20190424.112643-24.hpi) with following fix [here](https://github.com/jfrog/build-info/commit/2215d7d3d2880d938320522a1f0c8a77528325da#diff-8a1e5b219e67e7f2291ada4c78fd73bbL70) and then I get this error:

```
[Bitbucket] Notifying commit build result
[Bitbucket] Build result notified
java.io.IOException: Unexpected EOF
    at hudson.remoting.ChunkedInputStream.readUntilBreak(ChunkedInputStream.java:99)
    at hudson.remoting.ChunkedCommandTransport.readBlock(ChunkedCommandTransport.java:39)
    at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:35)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:63)
Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to stg-default-agent-eu
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1741)
        at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:202)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:954)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1071)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1060)
        at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.common.executors.NpmInstallExecutor.execute(NpmInstallExecutor.java:57)
        at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.scripted.steps.NpmInstallStep$Execution.run(NpmInstallStep.java:64)
        at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.scripted.steps.NpmInstallStep$Execution.run(NpmInstallStep.java:39)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
        at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException
    at hudson.remoting.Request.abort(Request.java:340)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:1038)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:96)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Is there anyone using Artifactory Jenkins plugin for building their NPM projects by scripted pipeline? If yes, can you share your configuration, please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It would be worth to check the logs at artifactory when you get this failure. Please upload the logs here

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved since Jenkins Artifactory plugin v3.2.3. Please upgrade to the latest version.
For more information see [HAP-1165](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP-1165) and this [commit](https://github.com/jfrog/build-info/commit/2215d7d3d2880d938320522a1f0c8a77528325da#diff-8a1e5b219e67e7f2291ada4c78fd73bbL70).